# Arraylist of Dates and SQL in VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, date, arraylist

I have an Arraylist of Dates as such

8/30/2020
8/27/2020
9/28/2020
9/9/2020
8/31/2020
8/29/2020

I then have a query with an in clause for the dates as such

```
   allQuery = "Select pj.ProjectName, tcd.Date, sum(tcd.Executed), sum(tcd.Passed), sum(tcd.Passedbug), sum(tcd.Flaky), sum(tcd.Failed), sum(tcd.Newfailures) "
    allQuery &= "From qastats.dbo.TestCaseDetails tcd inner Join qastats.dbo.Pipelines p on tcd.PipelineID=p.PipelineID inner Join qastats.dbo.Projects pj on p.ProjectID=pj.ProjectID "
    allQuery &= "where pj.ProjectName =@projectname "
    allQuery &= "And tcd.Date in (@dates) group by pj.ProjectName, tcd.Date"
```

I want to take the list of dates in the Array list and put it in this format (same as String.Join)

8/30/2020,8/27/2020,9/28/2020,9/9/2020,8/31/2020,8/29/2020

so I can pass them in as a value for the parameter

comm.Parameters.Add("@dates", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ListofDates

Is there a way to do it the way I want or a better way?

Thanks

Comment: You can't use a single parameter with a single value. You either need multiple parameters or else a single [table-valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters).

Comment: By the way, do you really have an `ArrayList`? If so, don't. The `ArrayList` class became obsolete in 2005. Use an array if appropriate or else use a `List(Of T)`.

Comment: My bad jmcilchinney.  Yes, I am using a `List (Of T)`

Comment: If you prefer the multiple parameter option, check [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?503298) out. It's practical if you're using inline SQL but the table-valued parameter is required if you're using a stored procedure.

Comment: The table valued parameter was exactly was I was looking for.  Works like a charm now!!!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested on the comments, use List instead of ArrayList.
Use a table valued parameter for the dates.
You'll need to create the table type in the database like this (I modified your query slightly moving the dates validation into a join if you want it in the where you can uncomment the commented line and comment the one for the join to `@dates`):

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.DatetimeTvp AS TABLE 
(
    value DATETIME NOT NULL
)
```

And then you can use this code:

```
Private Sub RunQuery()
    Dim dates As IList(Of DateTime) = New List(Of DateTime)({DateTime.Now, DateTime.UtcNow})
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

    sb.AppendLine(" Select pj.ProjectName, tcd.Date, sum(tcd.Executed), sum(tcd.Passed), sum(tcd.Passedbug), sum(tcd.Flaky), sum(tcd.Failed), sum(tcd.Newfailures) ")
    sb.AppendLine(" From qastats.dbo.TestCaseDetails tcd ")
    sb.AppendLine(" inner Join qastats.dbo.Pipelines p on tcd.PipelineID=p.PipelineID ")
    sb.AppendLine(" inner Join qastats.dbo.Projects pj on p.ProjectID=pj.ProjectID ")
    sb.AppendLine(" inner Join @dates dts on dts.value = tcd.Date ")
    sb.AppendLine(" where pj.ProjectName =@projectname ")
    'sb.AppendLine(" and tcd.Date in (select value from @dates) ")
    sb.AppendLine(" group by pj.ProjectName, tcd.Date ")

    Using cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), cn)
            Dim pDates = GetTvp("@dates", dates.Distinct())
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pDates)

            Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
            Dim sqlAd = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            sqlAd.Fill(ds)
            Print(ds)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Private Function GetTvp(ByVal name As String, ByVal dates As IEnumerable(Of DateTime)) As SqlParameter
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("value", GetType(DateTime))
    For Each d In dates
        dt.Rows.Add(d)
    Next
    Dim p As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter(name, dt)
    p.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured
    p.TypeName = "dbo.DatetimeTvp"
    Return p
End Function
```

Comment: This solution also has the benfit that you could JOIN against the tvp